# apex.submit does not change item value

Tags: jquery, api, oracle-apex

I'm trying to submit an APEX page, and toggle the value of an item between 'Y' and *null* in the process.

The most elegant solution appears to be

```
apex.submit({set:{"P1_ITEM":$v('P1_ITEM') == 'Y' ? '' : 'Y'}});
```

While I see the item change before submitting the page, it does not persist in session state.

Both these alternatives behave as desired, but involve an extra AJAX action.

Explicit item:

```
  $s('P1_ITEM',$v('P1_ITEM') == 'Y' ? '' : 'Y');
  apex.server.process("dummy",{pageItems:'#P1_ITEM'}
    ,{dataType:"text"
     ,async: false
     ,success:function(pData){
     }
   });
 apex.submit('GO');
```

This method doesn't show the item change on screen first

```
  var arrNames = [], arrValues = [];
  arrNames.push("P1_ITEM");
  arrValues.push($v('P1_ITEM') == 'Y' ? '' : 'Y');
  apex.server.process
    ('dummy'
    ,{p_arg_names: arrNames, p_arg_values: arrValues}
    ,{dataType: "text",async: false}
    );
 apex.submit('GO');
```

This is on 4.2.0, but also recreated here
https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=73000:33

Am I just misinterpreting indended functionality?

Answer (score 2):

Setting session state values with apex.submit() only works for form elements as far as i know.
If you change the item type in your example from "display only" to "text", the value persists.

Comment: Very true. The item in the example is a display only, and this only generates a span element. Setting that value will not change anything session-wise. `apex.submit`'s option "set" is different from providing page items to an ajax process: it will set the page item's value before submit, where the ajax processes will effectively push the value for the item to the server by providing it to the request headers. Indeed, allowing the display only to save session state would help. Or use a (extra) hidden item.

Comment: Thank you - that's it. I thought I was facing the same issue with hidden items - but there must have been some other problem.
There were some other logical issues with how my test case was written - which are now updated in the demo, I'm just not sure how I should update the example in SO.